$ x^{\lambda}y^{1-\lambda}\le\lambda x+\left(1-\lambda\right)y$ proof with differentiation
Let $x>0,y>0$ two positive real numbers.
Let $\lambda\in [0,1] $.
Prove the inequality above.
I tried looking at the function : $$ f\left(x,y,\lambda\right)=\lambda x+\left(1-\lambda\right)y-x^{\lambda}y^{1-\lambda} $$
Setting $\lambda =0$ or $\lambda = 1$ gives $f(x,y,0)=f(x,y,1)=0 $.
I then tried differentiating:
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lambda-\lambda y^{1-\lambda}x^{\lambda-1}=\lambda\left(1-y^{1-\lambda}x^{\lambda-1}\right)=0\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
\lambda=0\\
y^{1-\lambda}x^{\lambda-1}=1\Rightarrow\frac{x}{y}=1
\end{cases} $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\left(1-\lambda\right)-\left(1-\lambda\right)\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{\lambda}\Rightarrow\left(1-\lambda\right)\left[1-\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{\lambda}\right]=0\Rightarrow\begin{cases}
\lambda=1\\
\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=1
\end{cases} $$
$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial\lambda}=x-y-\frac{y}{\ln\left(\lambda\right)}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{\lambda}=0\Rightarrow x-y\left(1+\frac{\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)^{\lambda}}{\ln\left(\lambda\right)}\right)=0$$
How do I show that the minimum achieves $\min f(x,y,\lambda)=0 $ ?

We can use Bernoulli: The inequality is written as $(x/y)^\lambda \le \lambda (x/y) + 1 - \lambda$ which is true by Bernoulli inequality $(1 + u)^r \le 1 + ur$ for all $u > -1$ and $0 \le r \le 1$ (simply letting $u = x/y - 1$ and $r = \lambda$).

Suppose $\lambda>0$. Let
$$ f\left(x\right)=\lambda x+\left(1-\lambda\right)y-x^{\lambda}y^{1-\lambda} $$
and then
$$ f'\left(x\right)=\lambda(1- x^{t-1}y^{1-t}),f''(x)=(1-\lambda)\lambda x^{t-2}y^{1-t}. $$
Letting
$$ f'(x)=0$$
gives $x=y$. Note
$$ f''(y)=\frac{\lambda(1-\lambda)}{y}>0 $$
So $f(x)$ has a unique local minimum $0$at $x=y$. Note $f(0)=(1-\lambda)y>0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and hence $f(x)$ reaches the maximum $0$ at $x=y$; namely
$$ f(x)\ge0$$
which gives the desired inequality.

Taking logarithms on both sides, this is equivalent to showing that $$\lambda\ln(x)+(1-\lambda)\ln(y)\leq\ln(\lambda x+(1-\lambda)y)$$
for all $x,y>0$ and $\lambda\in[0,1]$, that is, proving that $f(x)=\ln(x)$ is a concave function.
But $f''(x)=-\dfrac{1}{x^2}<0$ for all $x>0$, implying this last condition.

Yes I have seen this proof, but I'm just curious how would one find it using partial derivatives.

I feel that is just an overkill: why work with more variables when this can be solved with simple single variable calculus notions?

I enjoy pain and suffering and I had this question on an exam today and I went by differentiating, didn't see this solution during it unfortunately , so I'm wondering if it is even possible.
